# Kivy on_touch_move and DragBehaviour not moving Image Widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am attempting to get my Player Image to move when triggered by an on_touch_move event. I have attempted use of DragBehaviour, which did not work. Similarly, updating the Player Image's x co-ordinate has no effect.

**code**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy import Config
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.vector import Vector
from random import randint

Builder.load_string('''
<Ball>:
    size_hint: None, None
    source: '58-Breakout-Tiles.png'
    pos: self.pos
    size: 15, 15

<Player>:
    size_hint: None, None
    source: '49-Breakout-Tiles.png'
    pos: self.pos
    size: 60, 30



<SettingsScreen>:
    close: close
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Image:
            id: close
            size_hint: .03, .03
            source: 'grey_crossGrey.png'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            font_name: "vgafix.fon"
            text: 'Music: '
        Switch:
            active: True
        Label:
            font_name: "vgafix.fon"
            text: 'Sounds: '
        Switch:
            active: True

<MenuScreen>:
    cog: cog
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Image:
            id: cog
            size_hint: .03, .03
            source: 'settings-cog.png'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Image:
            source: "brickbreaker log.png"
        Label:
            font_name: "vgafix.fon"
            text: 'Tap to start'

<GameScreen>:
    ball: ball
    player: player
    cog: cog
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Image:
            id: cog
            size_hint: .03, .03
            source: 'settings-cog.png'

    Ball:
        id: ball
        size_hint: None, None
        center: self.parent.center
    Player:
        id: player
        size_hint: None, None
''')

Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')


class Ball(Image):
    velocityX, velocityY = NumericProperty(0), NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocityX, velocityY)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class Player(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Player, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if (self.x >= 0) and (self.x <= self.width - 15):
                self.x += (abs(self.x - touch.x))

class Brick(Image):
    pass



class SettingsScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SettingsScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.previous = StringProperty('')

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.close.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.manager.current = self.previous


class MenuScreen(Screen):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.cog.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.manager.get_screen('settings').previous = self.manager.current
            self.manager.current = 'settings'
        else:
            self.manager.transition = FadeTransition()
            self.manager.current = 'game'


class GameScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.initWidgets()

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.interval = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.cog.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.manager.get_screen('settings').previous = self.manager.current
            self.manager.current = 'settings'

    def initWidgets(self):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = Vector(0, 4).rotate(randint(0, 360))
        self.player.pos_hint = {'top': 0.1, 'right': 0.6}

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()
        if (self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.y > self.height - 15):
            self.ball.velocityY *= -1
        # bounce off left and right
        if (self.ball.x < 0) or (self.ball.x > self.width - 15):
            self.ball.velocityX *= -1

    def on_pre_leave(self, *args):
        self.interval.cancel()


sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(GameScreen(name='game'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))


class BrickBreakerInsanityApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BrickBreakerInsanityApp().run
```

**Code assets (required):**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GAnv5DfjNUuAXTybmsan90Dm0OuSVOfb

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR799.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngYvL.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuxI3.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypd7C.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNvLz.png

Answer (score 0):

## Root Cause

The player widget is not moving because of `self.player.pos_hint = {'top': 0.1, 'right': 0.6}`

## Solution

### kv file

- Remove `self.player.pos_hint = {'top': 0.1, 'right': 0.6}` from method `initWidgets()`

#### Snippets - kv

```
Ball:
    id: ball
    center: root.center

Player:
    id: player
    y: root.height * 0.1 - self.height
    x: root.width * 0.6 - self.width
```

### Py file

- Add the method `on_touch_move()` into either `class Player()` or `class GameScreen()`:

### Snippets - Py: Method 1

```
class Player(Image):

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if (touch.x >= 0) and (touch.x <= self.parent.width - self.width):
            self.x = touch.x
            return True
        return super(Player, self).on_touch_move(touch)
    ...
class GameScreen(Screen):
    ...
    def initWidgets(self):
        self.ball.velocity = Vector(0, 4).rotate(randint(0, 360))
```

### Snippets - Py: Method 2

```
class Player(Image):
    pass
    ...
class GameScreen(Screen):
    ...
    def initWidgets(self):
        self.ball.velocity = Vector(0, 4).rotate(randint(0, 360))
    ...
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if (touch.x >= 0) and (touch.x <= self.width - self.player.width):
            self.player.x = touch.x
            return True
        return super(GameScreen, self).on_touch_move(touch)
```